How to read array in Spring projection
When querying SELECT p.id, JSON_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('id', pp.id)) AS photo_files statement in PostgreSQL I get:

For this I have specified this projection class:
interface ItemProjection {
    fun getId(): Long

    @JsonProperty("photoFiles")
    @JsonSerialize(using = PhotoFilesProjectionSerializer::class)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    fun getPhoto_files(): String
}

Serializer:
class PhotoFilesProjectionSerializer : JsonSerializer<String>() {
    override fun serialize(data: String?, gen: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider) {
        if (!data.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            gen.writeRawValue(data)
        } else {
            gen.writeStartArray()
            gen.writeEndArray()
        }
    }
}

However, I get:

Expected result:


photo_files for each item must be populated within photoFiles and not create a new array element.

My SQL query grouped by GROUP BY p.id, pp.id, when I had to only GROUP BY p.id.
